# Mockk android.graphics.Rect

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockk

I'm trying to mock the `top`, `left`, `bottom`, `right` properties inside android.graphics.Rect but I always get the error:

> io.mockk.MockKException: Missing mocked calls inside every { ... } block: make sure the object inside the block is a mock

I've tried several techniques, but they all produce the above error message:

```
val rectMock = mockk<Rect>()
every { rectMock.left } returns 123
every { rectMock.left } propertyType Int::class returns 123
every { rectMock getProperty "left" } returns 123
```

Comment: One of the rules of good mocking is: do not mock classes you don't own. Another is: do not mock data, and in particular value objects. Your are breaking both of those rules. Just instantiate the real `Rect` class. Using a mock just makes the code more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that `top`, `left`, `bottom` and `right` are variables, not methods so they cannot be mocked

```
public final class Rect implements Parcelable {
    public int left;
    public int top;
    public int right;
    public int bottom;
    ...
```

As @Augusto pointed out I shouldn't have mocked Rect anyway, and if I hadn't tried I would have been fine!

```
val rect = Rect()
rect.left = 123
```